# LinearLayoutManager on some device frozen app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hello I have a BIG problem with my app.

I Use recyclerview for show info with images and text's

it's ok. RecyclerView work good... on Xiaomi Mi3

but I was tryed launch app on Xiaomi Mi4 and app frozen.

I try coment some lines and I know so app frozen on this line

```
listdata.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

listtada is  `private RecyclerView listdata;`

when I launch app in Mi4 and active command is ↑ using CPU increase on 40% or more and app standing on line, not go next.

I don't know how it's in Mi4 difference from Mi3. android 6.0.1 ..

have you some ideas? or if want more info write, I send..

______________________________more code________________________________________

```
adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(IndexActivity.this, list_kone);
                        listdata.setAdapter(adapter);
                        listdata.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

my myRecyclerViewAdapter

```
ublic class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private List<Kon> listKone;
private Activity mact;

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Activity mact, List<Kon> listKone) {
    this.listKone = listKone;
    this.mact = mact;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != listKone ? listKone.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dlazdica_item, null);
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(listKone.get(i));
        }
    };

    view.setOnClickListener(listener);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, final int i) {
    final Kon feedItem = listKone.get(i);


    mact.runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            customViewHolder.viewpager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(listKone,i,mact));
            customViewHolder.indicator.setViewPager(customViewHolder.viewpager);
        }
    }));

    customViewHolder.txtnadpis.setText(listKone.get(i).getJazyky(0).getNadpis());
    // txtvhodnypre.setText(listKone.get(i).getNarodenie());
    customViewHolder.txtcena.setText(Integer.toString(listKone.get(i).getCena()));

    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] arrdatum = listKone.get(i).getNarodenie().split("-");
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(arrdatum[2]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(arrdatum[1]));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(arrdatum[0]));
        Date narodenie = cal.getTime();
        customViewHolder.txtvek.setText(Integer.toString((int) ((Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - narodenie.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25)));
    } catch (Exception e){
        customViewHolder.txtvek.setText("neuvedené");
    }

    customViewHolder.txtheigh.setText(Integer.toString(listKone.get(i).getVyska())+"cm");
    //   txtlokalina.setText(Integer.toString(listKone.get(i).getCena()));
    customViewHolder.cutpopis.setText(listKone.get(i).getJazyky(0).getPopis());
    String[] arrplemena = mact.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.plemena);
    customViewHolder.txtplemeno.setText(arrplemena[listKone.get(i).getPlemeno()]);
    // Then later, when you want to display image
}


class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtnadpis,txtvhodnypre,txtcena,txtvek,txtheigh,txtplemeno,txtlokalina,cutpopis;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    CircleIndicator indicator;

    CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        indicator = (CircleIndicator) itemView.findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        txtnadpis = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nadpis);
        txtvhodnypre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.vhodnyppre);
        txtcena = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cena);
        txtvek = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vek);
        txtheigh = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtheigh);
        txtplemeno = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_breed);
        txtlokalina = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_lokalita);
        cutpopis = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cutpopis);


    }
}


public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Kon item);
}


private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}
```

}

Comment: did you try by giving Orientation in linearlayoutmanager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked permissionsand on Xiaomi Mi4 I haven't allowed all.